# Can Mercurial repositories be nested?

Tags: mercurial, dvcs

What happens if there is already a Mercurial repository at

```
/User/peter/development
```

and now I want to add a repository for

```
/User/peter
```

because I also want to version `.bashrc`, `.profile`, or maybe `/User/peter/notes` as well.  Will having a repository above an already existing repository create conflicts for Mercurial?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Everything will be okay.

It seems that Mercurial is smart enough to ignore subdirectories which already have repositories in them. Here's a conversation with it:

```
$ mkdir outer
$ mkdir outer/inner
$ mkdir outer/sub
$ echo red >outer/red.txt
$ echo blue >outer/inner/blue.txt
$ echo green >outer/sub/green.txt
$ cd outer/inner/
$ hg init
$ hg add
adding blue.txt
$ hg commit -m "create inner"
$ cd ..
$ hg init
$ hg add
adding red.txt
adding sub/green.txt
$ hg commit -m "create outer"
$ hg status
A red.txt
A sub/green.txt
$ hg commit -m "create outer"
```

As you can see, when i add to the outer repository, it ignores the inner directory.

If you wanted to be extra sure, you could add the inner directory to your `.hgignore`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a ["subrepositories"](http://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Subrepository) feature that was added to Mercurial in version 1.3, and is
supported in 1.5, which allows some hg commands to act on nested repositories
recursively.